# For loop making multiple AJAX request, detect when finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a for loop that loops a bunch of times (1-1000+). In that loop, i'm calling an  ajax page to do some database stuff. I need a way to tell when the last item is done so i can refresh the page. What i did was run the loop and db code and right after do a refresh of the page, but what's happening, is a lot of the requests aren't done because it seems it's refreshing before some db updates are applied. How do i do this? Here's my code:

```
      for (i = 0; i < acIDs.length; i++) {

        var acID = acIDs[i];

        $.get('/ajax/db.asp?clientID=123&action=batchEditA&batchFieldA='+batchFieldA+'&batchValueA='+escape(batchValueA)+'&acID='+acID+'&pos='+pos);

      }      
location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Not at all an answer to the actual question, but if you're making 1000 ajax requests in a loop you probably want to rethink your design.

Comment: Rethink your design, and send the entirety up to the server in one single call, and refresh the page when you get the result.

Comment: This is the re-think! I was sending the request all in one shot with values and the like and it wasn't working. Query strings can only be so long before the browsers rejects it. This is my way of doing the call 1 at a time in a browser. Any ideas?

Comment: use `post` instead of `get`

Comment: just wondering, what difference does it make?

Comment: you already found out that get has character restrictions in url, post sends data in request body not in url

Comment: Tried that as well... no go. Same problem

Comment: I found a solutions that works for me. I simply, when the request is done, clearTimeout(timer); timer = setTimeout();  That way, the previous request will stop the timer if there is one, and the last request will start it and have nothing to stop it.